# Enumerate element with tag ol in for loop

Tags: django

I'd like to enumerate the elements in for loop with tag 'ol' with code:

```
{% for topic in topics  %}
    <ol>
        <li>{{ topic }}</li>
    </ul>

{% endfor %}
```

It displays

```
 1.Python
 1.Javascript
 1.SQL
```

When tried:

```
{% for topic in topics  %}
    <ol>
        <li>{{ forloop.counter }}{{ topic }}</li>
    </ol>

{% endfor %}
```

It outputs:

```
 1.1.Python
 1.2.Javascript
 1.3.SQL
```

Refactor the code as and works:

```
{% for topic in topics  %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{ forloop.counter }}. {{ topic }}</li>
    </ul>

{% endfor %}
```

The solution seem cumbersome, Could it be achieve in a straight-forwards way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just move `<ol>` tag declaration outside `forloop`,
to prevent new list creation on each iteration:

```
<ol>
{% for topic in topics  %}
    <li>{{ topic }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Note: Remove `{{forloop.counter}}`